# Excel copy text files based on column list

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

How do I expand this to copy files based on file name list in a column?  If file name is in column A, copy to the destination.

```
Dim fso As Object
Set fso = VBA.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Call fso.CopyFile(source, destination[, overwrite] )
```

This is what I found so far but it seems to copy one file and then it dies.

```
Sub ConditionalFileCopy()

SearchDirectoryPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\DP_From\"
TargetDirectoryPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\DP_To\"

    Dim nameValue As String

    'start at cell A1
    Range("a1").Select
    Do Until Trim(ActiveCell) = ""

        nameValue = ActiveCell

        file = Dir(SearchDirectoryPath)
        While (file <> "")

              'file matches the name, copy file
              FileCopy SearchDirectoryPath & file, TargetDirectoryPath & file
              GoTo NEXT_NAME
          file = Dir
        Wend
NEXT_NAME:
        ActiveCell.Offset(1).Select
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: `file = Dir(SearchDirectoryPath & "*.*")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove the line

```
GoTo NEXT_NAME
```

This is causing your loop to exit before the rest of the files are copied.

If you step through your code using <kbd>F8</kbd> you will see what is actually happening.